# Variable '' of type 'System.Data.DataRow' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees, rule-engine, runtime-compilation

I am trying to build generic function to apply rules on `DataRows`.

But I am getting following error while running the programe

Here is my code.

```
public Func<T, bool> CompileRuleDataRow<T>(Rule r)
{
    var paramUser = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression expr = BuildExprDataRow<T>(r, paramUser);
    // build a lambda function User->bool and compile it
    //Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expr, paramUser).Compile();
}
```

Function for building expression.

```
public Expression BuildExprDataRow<T>(Rule r, ParameterExpression param)
{
    ParameterExpression objExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
    string defaultMember = "Item";
    ConstantExpression indexExpr = Expression.Constant(r.MemberName);
    Expression leftIndexAccessExpr = Expression.Property(objExpr, defaultMember, indexExpr);
    ExpressionType tBinary;
    // is the operator a known .NET operator?
    ExpressionType.TryParse(r.Operator, out tBinary);
    var right = Expression.Constant(r.TargetValue);
    // use a binary operation, e.g. 'Equal' -> 'u.Age == 15'
    return Expression.MakeBinary(tBinary, leftIndexAccessExpr, right);
}
```

and I am calling it in this way in main method.

```
var rule = new Rule("Name", "Equal", "3");
Func<DataRow, bool> compiledRuleDataRow = CompileRuleDataRow<DataRow>(rule);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Address");
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
  dt.Rows.Add(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i.ToString());
}
//I want to do something like this.
    DataRow[] drFiltered = dt.Select().Where(r => compiledRuleDataRow(r)).ToArray();
```

And below is my `Rule` class

```
public class Rule
{
  public string MemberName { get; set; }
  public string Operator { get; set; }
  public string TargetValue { get; set; }

  public Rule(string MemberName, string Operator, string TargetValue)
  {
    this.MemberName = MemberName;
    this.Operator = Operator;
    this.TargetValue = TargetValue;
  }
}
```

When I run this code I am getting following error.

> variable '' of type 'System.Data.DataRow' referenced from scope '',
>   but it is not defined
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: variable '' of
>   type 'System.Data.DataRow' referenced from scope '', but it is not
>   defined

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: When I run your code, I get a different error: "Instance property 'Item(String)' is not defined for type 'System.String'". And I don't understand what that code is attempting to do (it's trying to do something like `s["Name"]`, for some undefined string `s`, which doesn't make any sense to me), so I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @svick, I'm getting a different error from the posted code.

Anyway, there are two problems with that `BuildExprDataRow` method. First, it's not using the passed `param` argument. Second, the property value is not properly converted, so the binary operators does not work.

Here is the fixed method:

```
public Expression BuildExprDataRow<T>(Rule r, ParameterExpression param)
{
    var right = Expression.Constant(r.TargetValue);
    var left = Expression.Convert(
        Expression.Property(param, "Item", Expression.Constant(r.MemberName)),
        right.Type);
    var comparison = (ExpressionType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ExpressionType), r.Operator);
    return Expression.MakeBinary(comparison, left, right);
}
```

Btw, the generic argument `T` is not used either inside that method, so you can remove it (make the method non generic).